# Shortcut triggers TAction on first created form instead of form with focus

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tactionmanager

I found (in Delphi 2010) that shortcuts always end up on first form (as owned by main form) that has that action, but not the currently focused form. My `TMainFrm` owns several `TViewFrm`. Each has a `TActionManager` with the same `TActons`.

I see some ways out, but wonder whats the best fix.. (and not a bad hack)

- The forms are navigated using a tabset which calls their Hide() and Show(). I'd did not expect hidden forms to receive keypresses. Am i doing something wrong?
- It seems that action shortcuts are always start at the main form, and using `TCustomForm.IsShortCut()` get distributed to owned forms. I see no logic there to respect hidden windows, should i override it and have it trigger the focused form first?
- Disabling all TActions in TViewFrm.Hide() .. ?
- Moving the `TActionToolBar` to `TMainFrm` but that is a pit of snakes and last resort.

Comment: I am thinking this newsgroup conversation is related: 
http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.vcl.using/shortcut-problem-suspect-taction/1076571

Comment: When forms are hidden, disable the action manager

Comment: There is no `TActionManager.Enabled`, i'd have to set `TAction.Enabled` or use its `TAction.OnUpdate()`.

Comment: Isn't there a `State` property like there is for action lists

Comment: Yes there is a `State` property.. did not see that. I found a workaround (see my answer) but this might be also be an answer!

Comment: I personally solve this with State

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround thats good enough for me; my main form now overrides `TCustomForm.IsShortcut()` and first checks visible windows from my list of editor tabs.

A list which i conveniently already have, so this might not work for everyone.

```
// Override TCustomForm and make it check the currently focused tab/window first.
function TFormMain.IsShortCut(var Message: TWMKey): Boolean;
  function DispatchShortCut(const Owner: TComponent) : Boolean; // copied function unchanged
  var
    I: Integer;
    Component: TComponent;
  begin
    Result := False;
    { Dispatch to all children }
    for I := 0 to Owner.ComponentCount - 1 do
    begin
      Component := Owner.Components[I];
      if Component is TCustomActionList then
      begin
        if TCustomActionList(Component).IsShortCut(Message) then
        begin
          Result := True;
          Exit;
        end
      end
      else
      begin
        Result := DispatchShortCut(Component);
        if Result then
          Break;
      end
    end;
  end;
var
  form : TForm;
begin
  Result := False;

  // Check my menu
  Result := Result or (Menu <> nil) and (Menu.WindowHandle <> 0) and
    Menu.IsShortCut(Message);

  // Check currently focused form   <-------------------  (the fix)
  for form in FEditorTabs do
    if form.Visible then
    begin
      Result := DispatchShortCut(form);
      if Result then Break;
    end;
  // ^ wont work using GetActiveWindow() because it always returns Self.

  // Check all owned components/forms (the normal behaviour)
  if not Result then
    Result := inherited IsShortCut(Message);
end;
```

Another solution would be to change `DispatchShortCut()` to check for components being visible and/or enabled, but that might impact more than i'd like. I wonder whether the original code architects had a reason not to -- by design. Best would be have it called twice: first to give priority to visible+enabled components, and second call as fallback to normal behavior.

Comment: Don't worry about the list we don't have, 'Forms' of 'Screen' always keep them respecting the z-order.